# Publishing to IIS - Core 2 BUT Targeting Full .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I've published to IIS in traditional web form apps, as well as numerous MVC apps. I can't seem to get my site to show up. Wondering if someone can point to a tutorial or post that could help me.

Comment: Please include the error message and/or screenshots. Also, be more detailed about the issue you are facing.

Comment: I am getting an HTTP 500. I am using IIS on my local machine first. Publishing remotely was fraught with issues so trying to do this simpler. It is a Core 2 app targeting the full .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

1. You need to publish your website and then point IIS website to the published folder
2. Application pool must be set to `No Managed code`
3. Application Pool identity user `IIS AppPool\{AppPoolName}` must have read permissions on the published website folder

Comment: I'm getting closer. Now I get access denied. I'm a little fuzzy on your third step. Where do I do that?

Comment: On your published folder, assign read permissions to Application Pool user who has name format like `IIS AppPool\{AppPoolName}` e.g. for DefaultAppPool the user will be `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`

Comment: I've got it showing the friendly IIS blue screen. And I got step 3 above taken care of.

Comment: Go to IIS Manager, select your website in left pane and then in the right pane double click the `HandlerMappings` and see handlers list is loaded? Also, are you setting it up as a separate IIS website or as a sub-application of some website?

Comment: Yes, there is a long list of handler mappings. This site is a site under the Sites node, alongside DefaultWebSite, which is turned off. Is it recommended to do that differently? Default Web Site has a program running that we use. They use the same port so one has to be off at a time.

Comment: Ok so your app is setup as a separate IIS website which is perfectly fine. So how are you accessing this website in browser using http://localhost? I am just wondering why the IIS default page is showing up

Comment: I am just typing "localhost" into the browser, or clicking on 'Browse' from IIS Manager.

Comment: localhost points to default website in IIS. If you need to browse other website locally, you need to add custom binding to your website e.g. local.testwebsite.com and then add an entry for this host in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file like this: 127.0.0.1 local.testwebsite.com then you can browse website using this host url

Comment: @Matt any update on this? Were you able to resolve the issue?